# compute mean with a threshold number of days for each month in r

Tags: r

I have an R time series data frame, consisting of multiple variables for each day for about 19 years of data. I would like to compute the mean of only the months which have more than 10 days of values. So, if a month (e.g. Jan for the entire period 1996-2015) has less than 10 days values, I would like to exclude it for the calculation of the mean-monthly for the whole time period.

The data frame is as follows:

```
        date val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
1 1996-01-01 5.25,4.20,3.58,6.44,2.66
2 1996-01-02 10.11,9.22,14.25,12.11,13.22
3 1996-01-03 25.11,30.44,45.22,31.24,27.35
..
..
..
7305 2015-12-31 30.54,55.14,63.12,51.22,45.21
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the number of observations per month with `aggregate` and then restrict your dataset to those which have at least *minDays* observations using `merge`.

```
x <- read.table(sep=c(","), head=T, as.is = TRUE, text=
"date,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
1996-01-01,5.25,4.20,3.58,6.44,2.66
1996-01-02,10.11,9.22,14.25,12.11,13.22
1996-01-03,25.11,30.44,45.22,31.24,27.35")

minDays <- 10
x$ym <- substr(x$date,1,nchar(x$date)-3) #get year month out of date
tt <- aggregate(val1 ~ ym, data=x, FUN=length) #Get number of observations per month
aggregate(val1 ~ ym, data=merge(x, tt[tt$val1>=minDays, "ym", drop=FALSE]), FUN=mean) #Calculate mean when n observations are >= minDays
```

Or using `ave`:

```
x <- read.table(sep=c(","), head=T, as.is = TRUE, text=
"date,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
1996-01-01,5.25,4.20,3.58,6.44,2.66
1996-01-02,10.11,9.22,14.25,12.11,13.22
1996-01-03,25.11,30.44,45.22,31.24,27.35")

minDays <- 10
x$ym <- substr(x$date,1,nchar(x$date)-3) #get year month out of date
x$n <- with(x, ave(val1, ym, FUN=length))
aggregate(val1 ~ ym, data=x[x$n>=minDays,], FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Comment: @MohsenSoltani Hope it works. If you can give an Example, how you compute the mean per month independent of the number of observations, I can update the shown method, that it fits your way to extract Year-Month from Year-Month-Day.

Comment: @ user10488504 Thank you so much for your help. I did plot the graph. Now I'm interested in to calculate and display the ''error-bars'' for each month (12 months). Any ideas?

Comment: @MohsenSoltani `aggregate(val1 ~ ym, data=x[x$n>=minDays,], FUN=function(x) c("mean" = mean(x), "sd" = sd(x)))` will give you mean and Standardeviation per month.